# Negating a quantified statement (no negator to move?!)

Tags: logic, quantifiers

**[Introduction to Languages
and The Theory of
Computation (click to read the content of the book)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.465.3774&rep=rep1&type=pdf)**

(This is not an exercise, but actual content from the blook explaining quantified statements)

> The general procedure for negating a quantified statement is to reverse
> the quantifier (change ∀ to ∃, and vice versa) and move the negation
> inside the quantifier. ¬(∀x(P (x))) is the same as ∃x(¬P (x)), and
> ¬(∃x(P (x))) is the same as ∀x(¬P (x)). In order to negate a statement
> with several nested quantifiers, such as

## 1

$$∀x(∃y(∀z(P (x, y, z)))) $$

> apply the general rule three times, moving from the outside in, so that the
> final result is

## 2

$$∃x(∀y(∃z(¬P (x, y, z))))$$

---

I don't get how they applied the general rule three times. More specifically, I don't get what you are supposed to do when there isn't a negator to move.

They write that you are supposed to "flip the ∃ and ∀" and move the negator, but what if there isn't a negator in the first place as is the case with statement #1?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a confusion about the phrasing of the exercise? If it says you should negate the proposition $p$, then you do something to get $\lnot p$. So your statement 1 should be negated, hence you take "NOT statement 1" and compute the wanted form.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege This is not an exercise.

Comment: So, you do realise that what happens from 1 to 2 is that they are negating the statement, which is formally adding the negator in the first place? You're talking about a method on how to approach negated propositions. If there is no negator, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege So are you saying that if there isn't a negator in the first place as in statement #1, then I should just flip ∃ and ∀ and not move anything (as there is nothing to move)? That's what I thought at first but that doesn't explain how the negator appeared in statement #2.

Comment: See my answer. Statement 1 and statement 2 are not the same, it is not a transformation of the same proposition. Statement 2 is the negation of statement 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're considering a method on how to negate propositions. Negating a proposition is formally just adding a $\lnot$-symbol in front of the whole proposition. That is, if we have a statement $A$, the negation would be $\lnot A$.

So your textbook is talking about negating $\forall x \exists y \forall z P(x,y,z)$. The negation then is $\lnot (\forall x \exists y \forall z P(x,y,z))$, which can be converted to another form $\exists x \forall y \exists z \lnot P(x,y,z)$ by logical rules.

(Consider for example the propositions "All apples are green" $\forall x P(x)$. If you negate this proposition you get "Not all apples are green" which is equivalent to "There is an apple that is not green". Formally: $\lnot \forall x P(x)\Leftrightarrow \exists x \lnot P(x)$)

If you don't want to negate a proposition, then you don't have to add a $\lnot$ and you don't have to swap quantifiers.

Comment: Oh, I see what I was missing now. I forgot that we initially had to add the negator symbol.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\neg(\forall x,\exists y,\forall z, P(x,y,z))&=\exists x,\neg(\exists y,\forall z, P(x,y,z))\\&=\exists x,\forall y,\neg(\forall z,P(x,y,z))\\&=\exists x,\forall y,\exists z,\neg P(x,y,z)\end{align}

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯${}{}$

Comment: Let me be extremely clear: my work on this question finishes with the present comment. I suggest you read more carefully the text you have quoted from your book, which talks about doing the calculation I have made.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it:

1. $\neg \forall x: \exists y: \forall z: P(x,y,z) \space \space$ (initial premise)
2. $\neg \neg \exists x: \neg \exists y: \forall z: P(x,y,z) \space \space$ (replaced "$\forall x:$" with "$\neg \exists x: \neg $")
3. $\neg \neg \exists x: \neg \neg \forall y: \neg \forall z: P(x,y,z) \space \space$ (replaced "$\exists y:$" with "$\neg \forall y: \neg $")
4. $\neg \neg \exists x: \neg \neg \forall y: \neg \neg \exists z: \neg P(x,y,z)\space \space$ (replaced "$\forall z:$" with "$\neg \exists z: \neg $")
5. $\exists x: \forall y: \exists z: \neg P(x,y,z)\space \space$ (removed each "$\neg \neg$")